# Skip iteration from yield block in ruby

Tags: ruby, iteration, block, yield

Trying to use an ill-conceived framework which collects a list of results from a passed-in block, effectively this:

```
def sigh(&block)
  r = (1..3).collect do |i|
     yield(i)
  end

  # do something with r
end
```

I want the block I pass in to filter the items, but to *skip* the collection iteration rather than adding `nil` to the results like `next` would (since the framework doesn't compact them.)  What's a simple way other than patching the gem?   I.e.,

```
sigh {|i|  next unless i == 1 }  # results in [1,nil,nil] rather than just [1]
```

Comment: I sense a monkey patch in your future

Comment: what's wrong with a the plain "sigh { |i| next unless i == 1 }.compact"? too verbose?

Comment: I need to pass a block into the framework method `sigh` which filters the results which the framework then acts on. Having `nil` in the results throws.

Comment: I now see what was asked. I cannot think of a way. `break` will escape from the entire method at that point.

Comment: Can you let it process the results you don't want, and then filter them out afterwards?

Comment: @Wayne: Unless it's an open source gem, in which case the best monkey patch may be a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is that you'll have to patch the gem.  Having your code block called by the gem doesn't give your code any special powers to affect how the calling code processes the block's return values.

The good news is that patching the gem can usually be done with a "monkey patch," where your program reopens the gem's class or module and makes the change.  In this made-up example, we'll show the class nested in a module, since many gems make use of nested classes and modules:

```
require 'somegem'

# Monkey patch to cause Somegem's do_something_cool method
# to ignore the SomethingBadHappened exception

module SomeGem
  class SomeClass
    alias_method :orig_do_something_cool, :do_something_cool
    def do_something_cool
      orig_do_something_cool
    rescue SomethingBadHappened
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you are asking for. If you post more details on the framework you are using, though, someone here may be able to help you think of a different way to work around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to patch, like others said. If you want a collection of `i` which satisfy some condition, the best choice would to replace `collect` with [`find_all`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all), and then you could use:

```
sigh { |i| i == 1 }   #=> [1]
```